# Game in Python (Dice)

Tags: python

my name is Erkan and i have problem with a game of dice im trying to build.

The core things i want to do is:

Ask the player of how many dices he wants. Minimun 1(ofc) and maximum 5. Each dice should only be tossed once.

The game should then randomizes results for each individual dice, one at a time, and prints this on the screen together with the sum of the tossed dice so far.

If any dice gets 1, then this is not added to the sum(like yatsy where im from), but two new dices are tossed. This should be displayed on the screen when / if it happens. As long as any dice gets 1, this procedure will repeat.

When all dice are tossed, the total sum and the number of dices tossed are printed on the screen.
The player should then have the choice to play again or quit the game.

I'm very beginner at Python and sorry for bad english.
Is it possible to get help on what im missing?

My code so far is this:

```
    from random import randint

   amount_dices=int(input("How many dices do you want to use? Min 1, max 5"))
   amount_dices_tossed = 1
    result=[]

    var1=0
    while var1<amount_dices_tossed:
     var1=var1+1
    for i in range(amount_dices):

     t=randint(1,6)
     result.append(t)
     print("Dices",i+1,":", t)
     Sum = sum(t)
     print(Sum)

    Sum_dices = int(sum())
    Sum_toss = str(sum(amount_dices_tossed))
    print("The total amount: " +Sum_dicesg + " and you tossed: " + Sum_tossed + " dices")

    choice = input("Do you want to play again? [yes/no]")
    answer1 = "yes"
    answer2 = "no"

    if choice == yes:

    else:
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        exit(0)
```

I dont know what it should say under "if choice == yes" when i want to start again.

Comment: Could you format your code with the correct level of indentations? It would make it easier to read.

Comment: code with wrong indentation is useless and don't expect answers.

Comment: if you want to restart then put code in `while True` loop and do nothing in `if choice == yes` - simple use only `if choice != yes:  print("Thanks for playing!") exit(0)`

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on the rules, but you have some errors in your code that are going to prevent you from running it, `Sum_dices = int(sum())` will fail because `sum` can't be empty, farther down there's a variable named `Sum_dicesg` in the string that prints the total.

Here's how I would write something like this:
https://gist.github.com/dashdanw/7a5c1db5407886bd77f2ce5d87aac52d
With the code examples I used here (i tried to use a bunch of pythonic tools) you should be able to get rolling and I don't want to accidentally write the whole thing for you by accident!

Answer (score 0):

To repeate code use loop `while True` and `exit()` or `break` to finish loop and finish game.

```
while True:

    # ... you code ...

    choice = input("Do you want to play again? [yes/no]")

    if choice != "yes":
        print("Thanks for playing!")
        #exit(0)
        break
```